# How to write custom logs in Google App Engine with java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, stackdriver

is there a way to programmatically write custom log entries from my App Engine application(running on standard environment) to the 'Custom Logs' on Stackdriver Logging?

I'm able to write custom logs using the gcloud command line tool:

```
gcloud beta logging write --payload-type=struct transaction-log '{ "user": "joe", "action": "UPDATE_PROFILE"}'
```

I would like to do the same from my application using the standard java logger. My app engine application writes all the logs under the "request_log" with lots of data from my requests that I don't need.

In my app I'm using the java logger like this:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger({classname}});
log.log(Level.INFO, "log message");
```

But, with this option I'm can only write logs with string messages. I would like to generte logs with custom payloads(JSON).

Thanks.

Comment: This question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977940/how-to-use-stackdriver-structured-logging-in-app-engine-flex-java-environment/58348848#58348848