# How to use Stackdriver Structured Logging in App Engine Flex Java environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google App Engine flexible environment automatically pipes stdout and stderr to Stackdriver (Google Cloud Logging). But this only supports plain text log message without any metadata (not even logging levels).

I found Logback appender for google cloud logging.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java

But this does not seem to support structured logging yet.
And also, it makes GRPC calls for every log entry under the hood. So, I wonder how scalable it is (especially compare to current app engine structure which has separate Fluentd agent handles logs).

Is there any out of box or simple solution to send structured log from App Engine to Stackdriver?

Comment: Have you looked at using the [Stackdriver Logging Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries)?

Comment: @ChristopherP Yes, this is the lower level solution, and I will end up implementing Logback appender using this API. I could do it, but I assume there is a solution provided by google when there is already Logback appender they made.

Comment: @essis, did you find any solution to send structured log from App Engine to Stackdriver?

Comment: See this answer for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74550227/6673169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Logback appender + Implement **LoggingEnhacer**

```
public class LogEnhancer implements LoggingEnhancer {


  @Override
  public void enhanceLogEntry(LogEntry.Builder logEntry) {
    // add Labels
    logEntry.addLabel("project", "conversational-services");

    // Transform textPayload to JSONPayload
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Builder structBuilder = Struct.newBuilder();
    String textPayload = logEntry.build().getPayload().getData().toString();
    try {
      // Validate JSON Payload
      mapper.readTree(textPayload);
      JsonFormat.parser().merge(textPayload, structBuilder);
      logEntry.setPayload(JsonPayload.of(structBuilder.build()));
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
      // Error reporting an error! FML
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // Do nothing (there is not a JSON Payload)
    }

  }

}
```

This class add labels and transform a JSON String in a JSONPayload

You need to specify the **LoggingEnhacer** on the **logback.xml** file

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
  <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <log>application.log</log> 
    <resourceType>gae_app</resourceType> 
    <!--  References to the LoggingEnhacer class -->
     <enhancer>[path_for_your_logging_enhancer_class]</enhancer>
    <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel> 
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you tell in which package is ObjectMapper? Maybe the list of imports would be helpful

Comment: @mmarquezvacas this is the package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Comment: You just did what I've been trying to do for months. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible to do structured logging in StackDriver logging. In fact, each individual log entry uses the [LogEntry structure](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry). As you can see it includes severity and metadata.

According to the [App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#appengine-vms), the following logs are provided out of the box:

> Request logs record requests sent to all App Engine apps. The request log is provided by default and you cannot opt out of receiving it.
>
> App logs record activity by software within the App Engine app. The
>   log is provided by default and you cannot opt out of receiving it.
>
> Runtime logs are provided from the flexible environment using a
>   preinstalled Logging agent.

Comment: the _App logs_ mentioned in the link is text only log for Java runtime. PHP runtime environment supports structured logging, but not Java. Implementing `LogEntry` is not an out of the box solution.

Comment: Would installing and using a Stackdriver Logging agent - https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#structured-log-install -  be a suitable solution for you (as described here https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Getting-more-value-from-your-Stackdriver-logs-with-structured-data.html) ?