# How to use jsonPayload on Logback with App Engine Standard (Java)?

Tags: logback, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm struggling to find a way to create log messages on StackDriver Logging on an App Engine Standard app (Java) using jsonPayload (structured log). If someone knows a reference please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using SLF4J?

Comment: @larruda Did you find any solution to this? I'm stuck as well.

Comment: I haven't tried since then. I switched to Node.js and now to Python and I was able to accomplish the same task easily with both. Good luck my friend. Let us know here if you can make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue to transform the JSON Payload
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/781

But you could use this Workaround and implement a LoggingEnhacer, to transform the TextPayload (JSON format) to JSONPayload

[How to use Stackdriver Structured Logging in App Engine Flex Java environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977940/how-to-use-stackdriver-structured-logging-in-app-engine-flex-java-environment/58348848#58348848)