# How to log as jsonPayload to stackdriver from google app engine using logback?

Tags: google-app-engine, logback, stackdriver

My spring boot app uses logback to log messages in json format. The app is configured to use consolelogappender (stdout).When the logs appear in stackdriver, they appear as textPayload instead of jsonPayload. Is it possible to write message to jsonPayload field in stackdriver using logback? If not, what are my options to log in json format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [Github Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/2669) it seems the issue all log entries are seen as textpayload. It has been added as a Feature Request but we do not have an ETA on when it will be available.

I'm not entirely sure if an alternative exist as Logback seems to be giving extensive log information, but if you are able to use the [Stackdriver Logging Client](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) instead, you could format the entry in order to get your object as a JsonPayLoad, although you will have specify most of the log categories yourself which can be an extra amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this, is to implements the transformation of TextPayload(JSON Format) to JSONPayload on the **LoggingEnhacer**

Check this answer [How to use Stackdriver Structured Logging in App Engine Flex Java environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977940/how-to-use-stackdriver-structured-logging-in-app-engine-flex-java-environment/58348848#58348848)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via google-cloud-logging-logback library.
However, please note following (from https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging):

```
Note: message is saved as textPayload if it is the only field remaining
after the Logging agent moves the other special-purpose fields and
detect_json wasn't enabled; otherwise message remains in jsonPayload.
detect_json is not applicable to managed logging environments like
Google Kubernetes Engine.
```

To add more data to json add an enhancer. Example:

```java
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import com.google.cloud.logging.LogEntry;
import com.google.cloud.logging.Payload;
import com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingEventEnhancer;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class EventEnhancer implements LoggingEventEnhancer {

    @Override
    public void enhanceLogEntry(
            LogEntry.Builder logEntry,
            ILoggingEvent e
    ) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("thread", e.getThreadName());
        map.put("context", e.getLoggerContextVO().getName());
        map.put("logger", e.getLoggerName());

        Payload.JsonPayload payload = logEntry.build().getPayload();
        map.putAll(payload.getDataAsMap());

        logEntry.setPayload(
                Payload.JsonPayload.of(map)
        );
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <log>application.log</log>

        <redirectToStdout>true</redirectToStdout>
        <resourceType>gae_app</resourceType>
        <loggingEventEnhancer>EventEnhancer</loggingEventEnhancer>

        <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```