# Cloud Logging API not showing JSON Payload

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am are using cloud logging APIs to publish stackdriver logs. I'm using an enhancer to convert a [textpayload to jsonPayload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977940/how-to-use-stackdriver-structured-logging-in-app-engine-flex-java-environment/58348848#58348848). I don't see any errors while I convert the payload. However, I do not see any data in jsonPayload on the console. 
I tested with textPayload and it works perfectly fine, Is there something clearly obvious that I might be missing. 
[image]

UPDATE: I got the jsonpayload to log but now, I see that only the values which are null are being logged. Non null values are not logged
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what document you are using? 
For reference have a look to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java)

Comment: See this answer for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74550227/6673169

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on how to log structured logs to cloud logging can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging

It sounds like your JSON is likely to be invalid if values are ignored and nulls are accepted. Perhaps quotes around text are missing?

I'd suggest you output your logs to console or a file and manually inspect the format.